# A Riemann surface with non-constant Gaussian curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, curves, riemann-surfaces, kahler-manifolds

I am finding some examples of a Riemann surface with non-constant holomorphic sectional curvature. Since any Riemann surface is of real dimension 2, such an example is reduced to an example with non-constant Gaussian curvature.

In fact, I want to find an example in a concrete way. I already know that any orientable (real) surface is Kahler, but such a fact is just about the existence of a Kahler metric. I think it does not provide any control over the curvature. So, I want to make a Hermitian metric on some surface so that the metric is determined by an explicit formula, and the Gaussian curvature is computable from that.

Do you know any such example?

Thanks!

---

Addition: I found an answer after some consideration, and I misunderstood some results that I mentioned. Actually, any oriented real surface with metric $g$ is itself Kahler by the existence of isothermal coordinates. Thus, any real surface with non-constant Gaussian curvature can be an example to my question.

Comment: Have you tried looking at (nonsingular) curves in $\Bbb CP^2$?

Comment: Hint: Take graph of a function $R^2\to R$ with the induced metric. Compute metric tensor and Gaussian curvature.

Comment: You should then answer your question and accept your own answer to keep this question away from the "unanswered list."

Comment: @MoisheKohan I will do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple answer to my question. First, note that if $(M,g)$ is a Hermitian manifold, then for any conformal change $\tilde{g}$ of $g$ also provides a Hermitian metric for $M$. Thus, for example, consider $M = \mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric $g$. Write
$$
\tilde{g} = e^{2f} g.
$$
Then, the Gaussian curvature is given by
$$
K_{\tilde{g}} = e^{-2f} (K_g - \Delta_g f) = - e^{-2f} \Delta_g f.
$$
Thus, by choosing some suitable function $f$, we can make $K_{\tilde{g}}$ is not constant. For example, put $f (z) = \vert z\vert^2$. Note that $(M, \tilde{g})$ is a Hermitian manifold with complex dimension $1$, so this is Kahler, and the Gaussian curvature at $p \in M$ coincides with the holomorphic sectional curvature at $p$.

Comment: I want to ask if the inverse process is solvable. I mean if given a non-constant curvature $K_{\tilde g}$, we can find a solution of the Liouville type equation for $f$. Hope somebody could answer this comment after all this time.